# Tensorflow loaded model cannot run on GPU

Tags: tensorflow

I'm facing a problem that the loaded model is not assigned to a GPU.
I'm using tensorflow 2.0 in ubuntu and this is happening on multiple platforms
1. Intel platform
2. Jetson TX2

Here is the sample code.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([...])
model.compile(...)
model.fit(...)

model.save("./mod.h5")

loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./mod.h5")

with tf.device("/GPU:0"):
    model.predict(...)  ## This will run on GPU

print("Start loaded model")
with tf.device("/GPU:0"):
    loaded_model.predict(...)   ## This version loads all the corresponding CUDA lib but runs on 
                                ## CPU with one thread

print("End loaded model")
```

Here is some log that I get but enabling debug info:

```
Start loaded model

... (Lots of GPU related log similar to the following)
2020-03-19 11:54:35.173142: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:54] sequential/bidirectional/backward_lstm/while/body/_62/add_2/y: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
sequential/bidirectional/backward_lstm/while/body/_62/add_3/y: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0
2020-03-19 11:54:35.173217: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc:54] sequential/bidirectional/backward_lstm/while/body/_62/add_3/y: (Const): /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0

(My comment: everything above is on GPU but actually runs on CPU. The GPU version takes 2 minutes but the CPU version takes 20 minutes)

2020-03-19 12:11:09.433786: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Out of range: End of sequence
         [[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]
         [[sequential/embedding/embedding_lookup/_5]]
2020-03-19 12:11:09.434200: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/base_collective_executor.cc:216] BaseCollectiveExecutor::StartAbort Out of range: End of sequence
         [[{{node IteratorGetNext}}]]

End loaded model
```

Can I know how to let the `loaded_model` run on GPU？Some options is missing from save and load?

I appreciate your time and help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. How about sharing your error ?

Comment: There is no error msg, I attached some log.